# SubMenu hovering to the left?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple sub menu which appears when u hover over the main menu.

Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

I have created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/KSeph/) for example.

Comment: Most of classes used in CSS are not existing in html!

Comment: Use either `float` **or** `position`, never use both. Every `position` value that's not `static` will remove your element from the flow, thus by rendering `float` useless.

Comment: the subsubmenu is absolute the submenu is floating, i have played around with the float and position thats why they are all in there

Comment: I would also recommend avoiding over-usage of `!important`... To my mind it's not a good way to learn `css` if you just try to *force* some behavior without clear understanding of what you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/KSeph/11/
It is not layouted but it works.

This css basically provides a very simple way to realize dropdowns:

```
.subMenu {
    float: right;
}
.subMenu ul li {
    float: left;
}

.subMenu ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}

.subMenu ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

.subMenu ul ul li {
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Almost layouted version: http://jsfiddle.net/KSeph/14/. Please include your thoughts and solution into your question, don't provide only a link to an external resource.

Comment: And btw. I really recommend not to use the original css... it's written to much circuitous IMO.

Comment: The original CSS doesn't use the child selector `>` at all, what makes it hard to maintain. If you use the child selector you can almost merge everything into a small set of rules.

Answer (score 1):

Hey now add two style in your css as like this

```
    .subMenu li{
        position:relative;}

.subsubmenu {
 position:absolute;
top:22px;
left:0;
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KSeph/15/)

Answer (score 0):

on `.subsubmenu` add `left: 0; top: 0;` and remove `float: right !important;`
on `.subMenu ul li` add `position: relative;`